# How to pass API returning data array values from Parent Component to Child Component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, amcharts4

In here I want to pass values of `this.bookingInfo = bookings.responseObj.txnValues;` `this.bookingInfo` array values from parent component to bookingInfo array in my child component.And i want to put those data in to  `chartNameChartTTV.data = [];` array in child component. In here `divName` would be accessing html file `am4core.create('divName', am4charts.XYChart);` not the bookingInfo array.

This is my parent component.

```
@Component({
      selector: 'app-dashboard',
      templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
    })
    export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{

      bookingInfo = [];
      ngOnInit() {
       this.getBookingInfo();
      }

      getBookingInfo() {
          const params = [];
          params.push({code: 'dateType', name: 'BOOKING'});
          params.push({code: 'fromDate', name: '2019-01-01'});
          params.push({code: 'toDate', name: '2019-12-31'});

          this.ServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params).subscribe(
            bookings => {
              this.bookingInfo = bookings.responseObj.txnValues;
              console.log(this.bookingInfo);
          });
      }
    }
```

This is my child component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary-chips',
  templateUrl: './summary-chips.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary-chips.component.scss']
})
export class SummaryChipsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() bookingInfo: [];
  ngOnInit() {

     console.log(this.bookingInfo);
  }

   createSummaryChips(  divName: string, chartDataInfo: [], chartValue: any, chartDate: any) {

    am4core.useTheme(am4themesAnimated);

    const chartNameChartTTV = am4core.create('divName', am4charts.XYChart);

    chartNameChartTTV.width = am4core.percent(100);
    chartNameChartTTV.height = am4core.percent(100);
    chartNameChartTTV.padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    chartNameChartTTV.data = [];
   }

}
```

This is my service class.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceHandler {
  getTxnInfo(headers: any[], params: any[]) {
    return this.apiService.get( 'analytics-api/dashboard/txn-info', headers, params);
  }
}
```

But when i try to `console.log(this.bookingInfo);` in child component it shows an error like undefined
This is my dashboard.component.html file

```
   <div class="l-content-wrapper c-summary-chip oh" >
          <div class="c-summary-chip__txt">Cancellations</div>
          <div id="divName" class="c-summary-chip__graph ">
          </div>
    </div>
```

But I want it put this code block in to summary-chips.component.html and put in
dashboard.component.html file like this

```
 <div class="l-content-wrapper c-summary-chip oh" style="visibility: hidden">
           <app-summary-chips></app-summary-chips>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the content of dashboard.component.html?

Comment: @Sujil Maharjan I added  dashboard.component.html code

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing to put in your bookingInfo from the dashboard to the app-summary-chips input

in the html of your dashboard component:

```
<div class="l-content-wrapper c-summary-chip oh" style="visibility: hidden">
     <app-summary-chips [bookingInfo]='bookingInfo'></app-summary-chips>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually i want to get data in to bookingInfo: [] in child component and put those data in to chartNameChartTTV.data = []; array inside createSummaryChips() method. I am drawing a xychart. After that i want pass 'divName' to here<app-summary-chips></app-summary-chips>

Comment: In that case, it's better to create a service that your child and parent component have access to. @Hansani. It is possible to pass data from child to parent but it doesn't look good, and creates an unusual dependency to the child

Comment: Can't we get data using above way using @Input() and put data in to chartNameChartTTV.data = []; array